# Cancel emulated hover event/color on touch device?

Tags: javascript, css, touch

Given this setup

```
a { color: #ccc; }
a:hover { color: #fff; }

<a href="#" id="abc">Test</a>

$('#abc').click(function() {
    doSomething();
    return false;
});
```

Everything "works" as expected, but "test" is left with white text on phone/tablets since iOS treats it as a hover now. What can I do to "reset" this?

Answer (score 0):

You move the focus to another element and the hover style is reset. E.g. Try to create another link, let's say you call them "link1" and "link2": when you click on link 1 it becomes white. Then you click link 2: link 2 becomes white and link1 will be back to its `#ccc` colour.

See this Fiddle (I just tried it on my iPad):

http://jsfiddle.net/uuFxR/

If you want to do it programmatically you have to work on the `.focus()` JQuery method, see here:

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: .focus() doesn't seem to have an effect... and I don't want link1 to return to gray ONLY when link2 is clicked. I wanted it to "reset" immediately - because in fact, there isn't really a hover to take place :S